# Retrieve WPF Windows and children state and content from a compiled running assembly

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering

Sorry in advance for the title. I'm just - not - able to find the good terms to ask it.

With Winforms, I know it was possible with some P/Invoke and with Handles to recursively get visual informations from a program.

So, can I 'manually' recompose a screenshot from a WPF application by obtaining informations about the different Windows and children from this application?

That would be the equivalent of using several methods like this one:
`static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);` to obtain Windows Forms information.

[EDIT]
Actually, I'm trying to hack myself. I'm remotely compiling applications on my server using the CodeDom.Compiler, and I'm curious if it's possible to receive a textual stream (XML or XAML) of what is happening in my app. (I plan on wiring my web application to the server with SignalR.)

What I can do if there's no way to reverse it cleanly:

I can add a method inside the app that will constantly (maybe every 1 second or on a screenshot XOR difference, though it's cpu intensive) check for all windows (controls) informations (ActualHeight/Width and absolute coordinates) and stream it to a socket.

Comment: what software are you trying to hack?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)?  It's open source and may do what you're looking for.  If not, it's open source so there's likely something in its source code that could be of use.

Comment: Oh, I checked your comment after editing my post. I'll use it!

Comment: It would be interesting to compare with an 'added' method inside my debugged program, since it's my own codes.

Comment: By the way, since you answered with an open source solution, you could put your comment as an aswer.